# What is the time complexity of this code? My teacher and I cannot agree

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I got this piece of code (function).

[image]

If I run it with n=10, it is called a total of 2047 times according to runCounter. If I run it with n=20 it is called a total of 2,097,151 times before completed.

According to my teacher, this code has a time complexity of O(n^2) but I cannot see why. 10^2=100. Nowhere near 2047 and 20^2=400, even more error. I think that this code is more in line with O(2^n) because 2^10=1024 and 2^20=1,048,576 which is more in line with the behavior of the function. Am I correct or is my teacher correct?

Is there any easy way to approach these problems? I try to write the Call stack on paper and get a feeling of what is happening but that is graphical, how do I write it in purely mathematical terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity actually seems to be `O(2^(n+1))`.  The methods calls being made in your recursive function will take the form of a balanced binary tree, whose height is `n + 1`, for an input of `n`.

With a problem like this, a good computer science approach is to just write out the number of method calls.  For an input of `n = 5`, here is what the number of method calls looks like:

```
n=5 -> n=4, n=4 (2 calls)

n=4 -> n=3, n=3 (4 calls)
n=4 -> n=3, n=3

n=3 -> n=2, n=2 (8 calls)
n=3 -> n=2, n=2
n=3 -> n=2, n=2
n=3 -> n=2, n=2

n=2 -> n=1, n=1 (16 calls)
n=2 -> n=1, n=1
n=2 -> n=1, n=1
n=2 -> n=1, n=1
n=2 -> n=1, n=1
n=2 -> n=1, n=1
n=2 -> n=1, n=1
n=2 -> n=1, n=1

n=1 -> (32 calls to n=0, then the recursion ends)
```

So, call with `n=5` generated:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 63 calls
```

This is equivalent to:

```
2^(5+1) - 1 = 2^(n+1) - 1
```

So, the complexity is actually `O(2^(n+1))`, not `O(n^2)`.  [Here is a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) to a Wikipedia page which also shows the same formula for the number of nodes in a balanced binary tree.